# batch file to count files in .zip files

Tags: batch-file

There are multiple zipped files say zip1,zip2 etc. Each zip file has multiple files in it. How do we create a batch file that only shows the number of files in the specific folder as
zip1 : 524 files
zip2 : 322 files

the code I made runs on other folders but not on zip files

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /D %%D IN ("folderpath\*") DO (
  FOR /F %%K IN ('DIR /A-D "%%D" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "File(s)" ^|^| ECHO 0') DO (
    ECHO %%D: %%K
  )
)
```

Comment: The code does actually not really appear to solve the task you describe...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a subroutine that uses [***zipjs.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) and counts the files within a zip file (it does not require external binaries):

```
@echo off

:countFilesInZip file.zip [out]
setlocal
set "count=0"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('
    call zipjs.bat list  -flat yes -source "%~f1"^|
    findstr /e /v "\\"
') do (
  set /a count=count+1
)

::echo %count%
endlocal & if "%~2" EQU "" (
    echo %count% 
) else (
   set "%~2=%count%"
)
goto :eof
```

to use it:

```
call :countFilesInZip  "c:\zipfile.zip" count
echo %count%
```

Comment: I am just a beginner at scripting, it would be a great help if you could elaborate a bit more :)

Comment: @MahadevanTyagi - you must download the `zipjs.bat` and put it in the same directory as the script you are using. Then you can put the subroutine above at the end of your batch file and call it in the for loop like `call :countFilesInZip  "%%~df" `

Comment: I am not quite sure what this statement means "above at the end of your batch file"

Comment: @MahadevanTyagi - I mean the subroutine in my answer. Check this for more info - https://ss64.com/nt/call.html